# Server/REST frameworks and where to start

Tags: java, rest, frameworks, server, libraries

I'm developing an Android APP and need to implement a Database and some REST services to connect each other. My REST services will be implemented in java using Spring MVC (or something similar) and deploying a WAR in a servlet (probably tomcat).I may eventually add a website too.

Since I'm new to servers, I'm looking into frameworks/libraries that are being used at the moment regularly to learn a bit about them and do things right.

So far I'm looking into:

- Jenkins: To deploy WARs automatically from a CVS and for CI if I get more people in the project.
- Docker: To separate the Database from Tomcat and to easily add up stuff to the server.
- Kitematic: UI for Docker to play around and learn how Docker works.
- Tomcat: Running WARs
- Subversion: CVS
- Spring/Spring MVC: Facilitate the development of REST services.

Is there anything else that is frequently used right now for this kind of setup?
For now I will create the server locally, and I know I probably don't need half of this, but since I'm trying to learn, and eventually get a real server, would like to do things as right as posible from the start.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1) if you want to use simple Java with JAX-RS, please read the tutorial from Oracle 
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giepu.html

2) if you want to build android based app, you can try for nodejs for simple rest service

3) Jetty server is enough to test Rest services and we can port to Tomcat later .